# Random Word Splitter

Tags: python, performance

I wrote a word splitting function. It splits a word into random characters. For example if input is 'runtime' one of each below output possible:

```
['runtime']

['r','untime']

['r','u','n','t','i','m','e'] ....
```

But it's runtime is very high when I want to split 100k words do you have any suggestions to optimize or write it smarter.

```
def random_multisplitter(word):
    from numpy import mod
    spw = []
    length = len(word)
    rand = random_int(word)
    if rand == length:       #probability of not splitting
        return [word]

    else:
        div = mod(rand, (length + 1))#defining division points 
        bound = length - div
        spw.append(div)
        while div != 0:
            rand = random_int(word)
            div = mod(rand,(bound+1))
            bound = bound-div
            spw.append(div)
        result = spw
    b = 0
    points =[]
    for x in range(len(result)-1): #calculating splitting points 
        b=b+result[x]
        points.append(b)
    xy=0
    t=[]
    for i in points:
        t.append(word[xy:i])
        xy=i
    if word[xy:len(word)]!='':
        t.append(word[xy:len(word)])
    if type(t)!=list:
        return [t]
    return t
```

Comment: Would `['ru', 'nti', 'me']` also be a possible output?

Answer (score 7):

Most of your variable names seem good, however `xy` explains nothing.

You should normally have two space's around operators.
`b = b + result[x]` is more readable than `b=b+result[x]`,
which looks at a glance like a variable.

Why do you need to import numpy to do a simple mod?
Python comes with mod, `%`.

You use the word `result`,
which I would use to imply that that will be the result of a function.

You shouldn't import things anywhere apart from the beginning of the file.
I nor anyone else wants to traverse you entire program to find that you import numpy's mod.
We want to know at the begging you use it.
Also this can lead to bugs where you think you have imported numpy, but you haven't.

Your programs overall ability to be read with ease is quite low.

---

I would recommend splitting the function into two.
A 'feeder' and a 'consumer'.

First I love generators, and you can write one that reduces the complexity of this program.

The algorithm that I use is to find the start and stops of the split.
Then I replace start with stop and add a random amount to the stop.
It really is that simple. To do the majority of your program.

```
def get_numbers(length):
    start, stop = 0, 0
    while stop < length:
        start, stop = stop, stop + random.randint(1, length)
        yield start, stop
```

This is simple, it will count until it gets to or past the length, and will return them.
You can think of it like building an array that looks like `[(start, stop), (start, stop), ...]`.

This is a near drop in replacement for the entire program until `for i in points:`.
However I use a lazy approach for that for loop.
Where yours is a one dimensional list of index.

If you wanted it to build an array instead then it would look like the following block.
However it's not advised, as it will lead to bad memory usage, and it will take slightly longer.

```
def get_numbers(length):
    list_ = []
    start, stop = 0, 0
    while stop < length:
        start, stop = stop, stop + random_int(length)
        list_.append((start, stop))
    return list_
```

Then you can now split the string.
To do this I will loop through the above generator and yield split strings.

```
def random_multisplitter(word):
    for start, stop in get_numbers(len(word)):
        yield word[start:stop]
```

I use Python's amazing split operation just like you did.
However as you want `random_multisplitter` to return a list, not a generator.
You will change it.
But a generator is a better choice for the 100k words input.
This is as then you will have a smaller memory consumption.

```
def random_multisplitter(word):
    return [word[start:stop] for start, stop in get_numbers(len(word))]
```

If not faster, it will at least be smaller and nicer to look at.

---

I thought that the program would be larger, and so, a small one function version would be:

```
from random import randint

def random_multisplitter(word):
    length = len(word)
    start, stop = 0, 0
    while stop < length:
        start, stop = stop, stop + randint(1, length)
        yield word[start:stop]

# Generator
random_multisplitter('runtime')
# List
list(random_multisplitter('runtime'))
```

---

Some people may dislike that I allow the slice to go above the maximum length of the list. Just to avoid any potential confusion about that, it's safe to use, but can seem weird.

```
>>> 'abcde'[0:20]
'abcde'
>>> 'abcde'[20]
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Due to this you may wish to change the assignment of `stop` to the following:

```
start, stop = stop, randint(stop + 1, length)
```

Or when you are returing the values change it to:

```
yield start, min(stop, length)
```

The former will have a higher amount of splits to the end of the string. Where as the unmodified version and latter version will prominently have two or three main splits on small strings.

---

As this is tagged performance, It's probably best if we have a speed test.
The code I use to test the speed is:

```
word = ' ' * 100000

def time_it(fn, name):
    n = 100
    t0 = time.time()
    for _ in range(n):
        fn(word)
    t1 = time.time()
    print name, '=', t1-t0
```

This uses `time` and so just take the results with a bit of salt.

Also, I can't test your original code.
`random_int` is not defined in the example.

And finally I used `start, stop = stop, stop + random.randint(1, 2)` On the 'Slow' ones, and `start, stop = stop, stop + random.randint(1, length)` on the 'Fast' ones.

```
Other Answer = 75.2860000134
Slow Generator = 12.1919999123
Slow List = 13.236000061
Fast Generator = 0.00200009346008
Fast List = 0.0019998550415
```

Keep in mind that Generators perform better when they aren't converted to a `list` straight off the bat.

Comment: In the list returning version of `get_numbers` you could append tuples for the `start` and `stop` values. Tuples are more efficient to create so it would be less of a resource drain. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/68817/4374739). Note that the answer is slightly wrong in that accessing a list is a little faster but it's still overall faster to use tuples in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You're right about quality of codes I'm trying to develop my skills by asking for suggestions. Somebody also suggested below code I think it's better on runtime.

```
def random_multisplitter(word):
    # add's bits will tell whether a char shall be added to last substring or
    # be the beginning of its own substring
    add = random.randint(0, 2**len(word) - 1)

    # append 0 to make sure first char is start of first substring
    add <<= 1

    res = []
    for char in word:
        # see if last bit is 1
        if add & 1:
            res[-1] += char
        else:
            res.append(char)
        # shift to next bit
        add >>= 1

    return res
```